How to end BuildRowSetFromString in a period
In my DE, I have a list of last 4 of account numbers in one field. The list is delimited by a pipe and will be different for each record in the DE (could be 2 account numbers, could be 100 account numbers). I am trying to format these into an email separating them with a comma and a space, then ending the list with a period.
How I want it to look:
"This message is applicable to your account(s) ending in: 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237."
Right now, the ampscript below shows it like:
This message is applicable to your account(s) ending in: 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237,"
How can I end this dynamic string of numbers in a period and not a comma?
 %%[ 
 var @acctList, @rows, @row, @rowCount, @acctArray, @i 
 set @acctList = AttributeValue('ACCT_LAST_4') 
 set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@acctList,",")
 set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows) if @rowCount > 0 then for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
 var @acctArray 
 set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */ 
 set @acctArray = CONCAT(field(@row,1),',')
 ]%% 
 
 %%=v(@acctArray)=%% 
 
 %%[ next @i ]%% 
 %%[ else ]%% 
 %%[ endif ]%%


You just need to put a check condition in the loop, and from there, it will check to see whether you reach the final row or not to put the period.
%%[ 
    
var @acctList, @rows, @row, @rowCount

set @acctList = AttributeValue('ACCT_LAST_4')
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@acctList,",") 
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows) 
if @rowCount > 0 then 
    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
        var @acctArray 
        set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
        if @i == @rowCount then
            set @acctArray = CONCAT(field(@row,1),'.')
        else      
            set @acctArray = CONCAT(field(@row,1),',') 
        endif
]%%

%%=v(@acctArray)=%%

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ endif ]%%


thank you! This worked like a charm.

@butternut_squash_100 if you find it helpful, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks
